# Include custom exception files in controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use Exceptions within my Models and Controllers. In the `application`, directory, I created a directory `Exceptions` that has some exception classes in files 'CustomException1.php' and 'CustomException2.php'.

I defined `MY_Controller` in `application/core`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();      

        // include Exception files
        require_once(APPPATH . 'Exceptions/CustomException1.php');
        require_once(APPPATH . 'Exceptions/CustomException2.php');
    }

}
```

In my controller `Test` :

```
class Test extends MY_Controller {
   public function index() {
      try {
         throw new CustomException1('This is a custom exception');
      } catch (CustomException1 $e) {
         $this->output->set_status_header('500');
         echo $e->message;
      }
}
```

Now, I would expect this to work since I'm requiring all the files that define the Exception classes, but I still get an error stating

`Class CustomException1 not found on line xx`

Answer (score 0):

```
throw new CustomException1('This is a custom exception');
```

and
    catch (CustomException $e)

tbh, this more looks like a typo. The thrown exception `CustomException1` should be `CustomException`

Comment: Ah, that would be an error I made when posting the question. I renamed the actual exceptions I'm throwing to `CustomException`. I'll fix that now, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, including the files from the Exceptions directory just wouldn't work in CI. Placing them in the `libraries` directory and loading them in using `$this->load->library()` also would not have worked because CI attempts to instantiate the libraries at the time of loading in, which of course, I did not want.

I ended up putting them in a directory `exceptions` within `helpers`, and load them in at `MY_Controller` using `$this->load->helper('Exceptions/CustomException');`.

It is important to note that when loading in a helper, CI converts the entire path to lowercase and appends `_helper` to the end of the filename, so the exact path of my exception class on the server is

`APPPATH . 'helpers/exceptions/customexception_helper.php'`

This is my modified base class controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();      

        $this->load->helper("Exceptions/CustomException1.php");
        // includes file APPPATH . 'helpers/exceptions/customexception1_helper.php'

        $this->load->helper("Exceptions/CustomException2.php");
        // includes file APPPATH . 'helpers/exceptions/customexception2_helper.php'
    }
}
```

Once included this way using `MY_Controller`, these exceptions can then be used in models as well without needing to re-load them in `MY_Model`.

*PS - I'm not completely satisfied with this solution, and it seems a little hack-y, but this might be the only way to integrate exceptions into CodeIgniter.*